# How can I specify linker options in Rust like "#pragma comment(linker, ...)"?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/merge:. data=. text")
#pragma comment(linker, "/merge:. rdata=. text")
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:. rdata=. text")
```

i try that, but ....

```
#[link_section = "/merge:. data=. text /merge:. rdata=. text /section:. rdata=. text"]
```

As a result, it adds a section directly.. it's bad

How should I implement it in rust

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this command:

```
cargo rustc -- -C link-args="/merge:.data=.text /merge:.rdata=.text /section:.text,RWE"
```